# Trouble shooting issues with capybara not submitting a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I'm currently stuck with a failing test on an application I'm working on.

**The situation is as follows:**

I load a form for a new resource using AJAX as the form is in a bootstrap light box. I do this by simply appending a partial containing the light box and form. The form is filled in and submitted the create action redirects back to the page and therefore loads with the newly created resource displayed in a table.

I will hold off from putting any code up because the process does work when completed manually; I don't think that it is an issue with the code but more likely an issue with Selenium. Also, The other questions I've read on this topic seem to be very specific, I'd like to get a more general answer for troubleshooting selenium/capybara issues like this.

Obviously, if you do want to see any aspect of the code, please let me know

**Here are some relevant facts:**

- The process that the test is simulating does in fact work when completed manually.
- The failure message is pretty unhelpful, it is simply the error I'd expect if the form had not been submitted (expected to find "some text from the newly created resource").
- As stated the form is kept in a bootstrap light box (Javascript is enabled and I am using Selenium)
- When Firefox gets to the point of clicking the submit button, it looks like it is pressed but then hangs
- prior to clicking the button, the rest of the Javascript seems to work (namely appending a partial containing the light box).
- The form relates to the new/create actions
- trying to output to the console from the new/create actions results with only output from the new action (form is obviously not getting submitted)
- I'm using selenium-webdriver (2.40.0) and capybara (2.2.1)

Has anybody else had this kind of issue? Is there anyway that I can isolate where the problem is?

Thanks in Advance

Daz